# How to write an ODE with a Darboux polynomial?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, integrable-systems

**Question:** Given a polynomial ODE $\dot{x}=f(x)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that possesses a Darboux polynomial$^*$ $p(x)$ satisfying $\dot{p}(x)=c(x)p(x)$ for some function $c(x)$ (called the cofactor) how can one write $f(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ and/or $c(x)$?

**Example:** To make things a little more concrete with an example, let $H(x)$ be a first integral satisfying $\dot{H}(x)=0$  (this is the $c(x)=0$ case). Then an ODE possesses a first integral $H(x)$ iff it can be written in the following skew-gradient form
$$\dot{x}=S(x)\nabla H(x),$$ for some matrix $S(x)=-S(x)^T$. My question is: is there an equivalent statement for the case of ODE possessing a Darboux polynomial?

**My initial thoughts:** you can let $$f(x) = \frac{c(x)p(x)}{\nabla p(x)^T A \nabla p(x)} A \nabla p(x)$$ for some matrix $A$, then $f(x)$ has $p(x)$ as a Darboux polynomial. However, this relies on $ \frac{c(x)p(x)}{\nabla p(x)^T A \nabla p(x)}A$ being polynomial for $f(x)$ to also be polynomial. Also this doesn't really fit with the above first-integral case when $c(x)\rightarrow 0$.

$^*$ Darboux polynoimals are also known as second integrals or weak integral for non-polynomial ODEs.

**Edit:** As suggested, including a skew symmetric matrix $S=-S^T$ would make $f$ satisfy the first integral condition on its level set  ($c(x)\rightarrow 0$ or $p(x)\rightarrow 0$), that is:

$$f(x) = \left(\frac{c(x)p(x)}{\nabla p(x)^T A \nabla p(x)} A + S\right)\nabla p(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The following should solve your problem under the assumption that $\nabla p(x)$ is an everywhere non-vanishing vector field:

You want $\nabla p\cdot f = c p$, so let $\alpha = c p / |\nabla p|^2$, then $\nabla p \cdot (f - \alpha \nabla p) = 0$ and you are back to your first example. Find a skew symmetric $S$ so that $X:=f-\alpha \nabla p = S \nabla p$. Then $f=(\alpha I + S) \nabla p$ has the required form.

If the data in your question are given, then $f$ is already assumed to be  a polynomial.

In order to obtain a skew symmetric map $S$ as above, at a point $x$ we define the linear map  $S_x:{\Bbb R}^n \to {\Bbb R}^n$ by declaring (omitting the base point  $x$ in the notation):

$$ S Y = \frac{X (\nabla p \cdot Y)- \nabla p (X \cdot Y)}{|\nabla p|^2}  \ \ Y \in {\Bbb R}^n .$$
By construction, $Y \cdot (S_x Y)=0$ for all $x$ and every $Y\in {\Bbb R}^n$, so $S_x$ is represented by a skew-symmetric matrix in any orthonormal basis of ${\Bbb R}^n$.
Also, as required, $S_x(\nabla p) = X$ since $X\cdot  \nabla p = 0$.

Comment: I agree that including the skew symmetric matrix is the way to go. Can you show that given any ode vector field $f$ with a darboux poly $p$, then it can always be written in this form?

Comment: @Ben94 Have you made any progress in regards to this question?

Comment: Hi @NicAG, no not really. I published a paper related to the topic, but never solved this problem. I am still interested in it, tho I am working on other topics now. Would this result be of use for you?

Comment: Yes, it would be indeed. What is the name of the paper?

Comment: The title of the paper is "On the preservation of second integrals by Runge-Kutta methods". It doesn't really give any new results on Darboux polynomials, but focuses on their relation with some popular numerical methods. Please don't hesitate to reach out if you'd like to discuss! :)

Comment: @Ben94. Sorry for getting back to you so late. I've seen the paper. It is interesting but not exactly what I am searching for. I am really interested in how to write the general ode having a specific Darboux polynomial. Especially, given some algebraic solution. Can we bound the number of polynomial odes havin this algebraic solution, given a certain degree of the polynomial ode

Comment: @NicAG that sounds like a tough but interesting question! Check out the paper "Geometric integration using discrete gradients". On the top of page 1032 the authors talk a bit about this problem. Tho they do not solve it. They do say that generally systems of the form $f=(A+S)\nabla p$ should be considered, as we have above. I have edited the question to reflect my current best guess at this. If we could show that there always exists an $A$ and $S$ that solves this, then that might be a good starting point.

Comment: @Ben94 Looking at the proof of theorem 3 in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371244_Transcendental_Limit_Cycles_Via_the_Structure_of_Arbitrary_Degree_Invariant_Algebraic_Curves_of_Polynomial_Planar_Vector_Fields, I think this paper solves the problem in 2d. But the answer seems quite ugly but generalizable to higher dimensions